How to build SSL enabled for Ada Web Server?
I'm trying to get HTTPS requests working with Ada Web Server (AWS) found at https://github.com/AdaCore/aws/tree/master
I'm on Windows 11 and I don't understand how to make a build of the library and then use it with my project. The library wants me to edit "makefile.conf" and for my use cases - I have to specify XMLADA=True and ssl=openssl. I'm not sure where to add the "Ada_Project_Path" but I made a variable at the top of the conf file which I called that and stored the directory to my GPR file for the project.
I tried downloading MingW32 and Git Bash to use the make command to do "Mingw32-make setup" as the conf file stated but I was unable to build the library - getting an error about "grep not being found". The GCC, Mingw32-make are in my Path and I have checked by doing "--version".
Can anyone provide me with some guidance on how to build this library with Windows -  perhaps by using Alire as that is what I originally used for dependencies. I will switch to GPRBuild if that helps.
After I've built the library, do I just use "with "aws"" in my GPR project file to import it - I previously used Alire which handled this for me.
Thanks

Possible duplicate of How to do HTTPS requests in Ada Web Server?. Please consider editing the original question to reflect new findings and focus on a specific problem that you encounter.

Made the change - if u know anything to solve my issue though please let me know

Does this answer your question? How to do HTTPS requests in Ada Web Server?

Not really, the suggestion made in there is what I tried and failed to do. I get that I need to edit my makefile config but after that I don't know how to build it and link it to my ada project as I'm using alire.

Sorry for the confusion; the comment to which you responded was automatically generated after a vote to close this question.
